# Using Kotlin reflection sealedSubClasses property in Android release build

Tags: android, kotlin, reflection

When I am trying to use the `sealedSubClasses` attribute of a reified class in Kotlin, it only works in my debug and not in my release build. I guess this is a problem with ProGuard, but I don't know how to fix this. I already tried keeping all classes in the module where the sealed class is, but I am having no luck with this. The `sealedSubClasses` property always returns an empty list.

Answer (score 10):

Found two ways to fix this issue:

1. Add rule to your proguard-rules.pro file:

```
    -keep class com.example.ClassName { *; }
    -keep class com.example.ClassName$* { *; }
```

2. Use @Keep annotation:

```
    @Keep
    sealed class ClassName{
        @Keep
        object A : ClassName()
        @Keep
        object B : ClassName()
    }
```

This one didn't work for me:

```
-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }
```

Also there is a bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169264693 that could be the part of your problem.

Comment: option #2 worked for me (and is so awesome and easy)

Comment: As a small addition to 1.: When the subclasses are enums you have to use this: `-keep enum com.example.ClassName$* { *; }`

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }
```

to get missing attributes from your class

Comment: I assume you mean ProGuard config. The answer would be useful for wider audience if you'd specify where to add the line.

Answer (score 0):

Try This, worked for me:

1. Utilize an interface for improved structure.
2. Implement sealed classes with the mentioned interface if you prefer maintaining the names.
3. Include the following ProGuard entry:

   ```
   -keepnames class * implements full_qualified_interface_name {
       *;
   }
   ```

Alternatively, use a pattern if your sealed classes share specific common names.

Answer (score -3):

Add an additional rule to your proguard file:

```
-keepnames class com.fully.qualified.ClassName* {
    *;
}
```

Notice the asterisk character.